# Scheduled Report is getting failed in jasper (others are working )

Tags: jasperserver

My others scheduled reports are working fine, the one report is throwing below error message.  Its bit hard to find the issue.

> 2019-02-20 12:05:26,245 ERROR ReportExecutionJob,quartzScheduler_Worker-2:366 - The job error notification was not completed. An error occurred while sending it. (Error UID: 3370ec29-7b9d-4f36-a459-5b8957a6b2be)
>   org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
>     nested exception is:
>       java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed); message exception details (1) are:
>   Failed message 1:
>   javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
>     nested exception is:
>       java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
>       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:625)
>       at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:416)
>       at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
>       at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:336)
>       at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJobMailNotificationImpl.sendMailNotification(ReportExecutionJobMailNotificationImpl.java:140)
>       at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.sendMailNotification(ReportExecutionJob.java:1123)
>       at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.executeAndSendReport(ReportExecutionJob.java:581)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have republished with minimal changes, it works charm. Still jasper logging system is not clear as like others.